# How do I replace a cell's contents when it matches a specific string?

Tags: r

I have this line working:

```
access$`Reading Score` <- gsub('NA', '', access$`Reading Score`)
```

However, I'd like to apply the same thing to 20+ more columns. Without having to explicitly write out all 20 column changes, is there a way to do this when the cell's contents exactly match `'NA'`? I have a few columns that are people names so they have the string `NA` but I obviously don't want to apply the changes to those names, just the 20 columns where the entire cell's contents is `'NA'`

Also, what should the second statement be if I want to properly replace with a NULL value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier way may be to not let "NA" into the data in the first place.  E.g., you can call

```
library(readxl)
readxl::read_excel(path, na = "NA")
```

and it will convert all the "NA" to `NA`.  `read_delim`, `read_csv` and related also have similar options.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do an exact match use `==`. You can use `lapply` to apply a function for multiple columns. If you have string `'NA'` and if you want to replace it by the empty value you can do :

```
access[1:20] <- lapply(access[1:20], function(x) {x[x == 'NA'] <- '';x})
```

You can replace `''` with `NA` if you want to replace it `NA`.

---

In `dplyr` you can replace first 20 columns with `NA` using `na_if` :

```
library(dplyr)
access %>% mutate(across(1:20, na_if, 'NA'))
```

---

As suggested by @Onyambu we can directly change the values for all the columns.

```
access[1:20][access[1:20]=="NA"] <- ''
#Or
access[1:20][access[1:20]=="NA"] <- NA
```

Comment: why use `lapply`? why not `access[1:20]<- access[1:20]=="NA"`

Comment: I guess what you mean is `access[1:20][access[1:20]=="NA"] <- ''` ? Yeah, that's much better. Forgot about that.

Comment: I was trying this answer until David T's answer resolved it. I was getting the following error: `Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) :  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format` Any idea what that means? I'm struggling to also fully understand what @Onyambu's answer is doing.

Comment: I think the columns have different type maybe `POSIXct` hence, it has issues converting to `NA`. it is usually better to provide data in a reproducible format to avoid such issues. Anyway, if it is possible for you to go back and read the data again then you should definitely do that.